# MySQL syntax error when creating a lab test table

Tags: mysql

I am learning simple sql to create a database of lab tests in MySQL. The syntax can be found below. I keep getting `an error code 1064 (42000)` and cannot figure out why:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE xiao (level CHAR (1), fullname VARCHAR (50),
name VARCHAR (50), basecode VARCHAR (20), 
LOINC curation VARCHAR (10),
PRIMARY KEY (LOINC curation)
);
```

The error code tells me to

> check the syntax to use near curation VARCHAR (10), PRIMARY KEY (LOINC
>   curation))

Comment: Thanks a million, Digital Chris. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a space in the name like that. `LOINC curation` could be `LOINCcuration` or `LOINC_curation`...

If you REALLY want to include spaces in fieldnames, you surround them with backticks like:

```
CREATE TABLE xiao (level CHAR (1), fullname VARCHAR (50), name VARCHAR (50), 
basecode VARCHAR (20), `LOINC curation` VARCHAR (10), 
PRIMARY KEY (`LOINC curation`) );
```

Comment: You can't have `-` in a name without escaping it, either. That's used for subtraction.